# How to find an intersection of a list of dataframes with exactly same columns and indexes but different values in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of pandas dataframes as:

```
lis = [df1, df2, df3, ... , dfn]
```

I want to find an intersection of these dataframes such that my final df called 
intersection_df have only values that are common to all. All columns and rows should still be there but filled with na if no intersection is found.

My dataframes are all multidimensional with same number of rows and columns which look like this like this:

```
              1   2   3   4   5  
cat   cat     1   0   0   1   1  
      dog     1   0   0   1   1  
      fox     0   0   0   0   0  
      jumps   0   0   1   1   1  
      over    1   0   0   1   1  
      the     1   0   0   1   1
dog   cat     1   0   0   1   0  
      dog     1   0   0   1   0  
      fox     0   0   0   0   0  
      jumps   1   0   0   1   0  
      over    1   0   0   1   0  
      the     1   1   0   1   0
```

I have tried different solutions found on stackoverflow but no luck, any ideas?

Comment: how many data frames are in your example? I don't quite understand the formatting

Comment: @Blake thanks for the edit.  You might be correct, but you're guessing just as I was.  However, I like your guess better (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

lis = [df1, df2, df3, ... , dfn]

inner_align = lambda d1, d2: d1.align(d2, 'inner')[0]
outer_align = lambda d1, d2: d1.align(d2, 'outer')[0]

inner_indcs = reduce(inner_align, lis)
outer_indcs = reduce(outer_aling, lis)

innout = lambda d, i, o: d.reindex_like(i).reindex_like(o)

output = innout(lis[0], inner_indcs, outer_indcs)
```

---

**Setup**

```
lis = [
    pd.DataFrame(1, list('abc'), list('xyz')),
    pd.DataFrame(1, list('acd'), list('wyz')),
    pd.DataFrame(1, list('bec'), list('ysu')),
    pd.DataFrame(1, list('cef'), list('xgy')),
]

print(*lis, sep='\n'*2)

   x  y  z
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1

   w  y  z
a  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
d  1  1  1

   y  s  u
b  1  1  1
e  1  1  1
c  1  1  1

   x  g  y
c  1  1  1
e  1  1  1
f  1  1  1
```

---

**Demonstration**

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

inner_align = lambda d1, d2: d1.align(d2, 'inner')[0]
outer_align = lambda d1, d2: d1.align(d2, 'outer')[0]

inner_indcs = reduce(inner_align, lis)
outer_indcs = reduce(outer_align, lis)

innout = lambda d, i, o: d.reindex_like(i).reindex_like(o)

output = innout(lis[0], inner_indcs, outer_indcs)

print(output)

    g   s   u   w   x    y   z
a NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN
b NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN
c NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN
d NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN
e NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN
f NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

Comment: This looks good but the final product should be a single dataframe, not a list of same dataframes.

Comment: @Elisha512 I'm glad it's helpful... but how would I know what your final output should look like if you don't show us.  I had to guess at creating sample data in the first place.  Why don't you take my sample data and edit your post.  Include in it what you want the final dataframe to look like.